# Altering data in site through VBA Excel

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to change the value in a website through the below code but how do I click the `Submit` button through code?

Also what if my `.Navigate` value should keep moving from A1-->A2--> and so on instead of a static value? (How do I use a `For` loop in the place of `.Navigate`)?

```
Sub FillForm()
    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Navigate "https://www.morovia.com/bulk-check-digit-calculation/index.php"
    IE.Visible = True
    While IE.busy
        DoEvents
    Wend
    IE.Document.All("").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("b1")
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things to note:

1) You need to use a proper wait line in your code:

```
While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
```

2) The submit button has an id. This is normally the fastest retrieval method so use that.

```
ie.document.querySelector("#submit").click
```

3) Use ids throughout where possible. For example, when entering initial search number

```
ie.document.querySelector("#sourceNumbers").value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").value
```

4) The most up to date method for navigate is:

```
ie.navigate2
```

5) Always have another wait line after a `.click` or `.submit` to allow page to load new content

6) Always remember to `.Quit` the application to prevent processes from continuing to run and potentially lead to lack of system resources.

```
Public Sub FillForm()
    Dim ie As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.morovia.com/bulk-check-digit-calculation/index.php"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        .document.querySelector("#sourceNumbers").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value

        .document.querySelector("#submit").Click

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Debug.Print .document.querySelector("#results").Value
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

---

A loop over links in columns A might look like:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub LoopLinks()
    Dim ie As Object, ws As Worksheet, arr(), i As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    arr = Application.Transpose(ws.Range("A1:A3").Value) '<== amend range as required

    With ie
        .Visible = True

        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            If InStr(arr(i, 1), "http") > 0 Then '<=check is an URL
                .Navigate2 arr(i)

                While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

                'do something......
            End If
        Next
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer looks good. Might be worth adding that the website is a "Bulk check digit calculator". It does not make sense for the client to send one request for each cell's content. Maybe it would be good to read all cell values into an array, `join` said array using `vbNewLine` as delimiter, then submit the resultant string. But that's up to you/OP really.

Comment: @chillin Yeah. I read into an array for the bottom version. I leave the 'do something bit vague as I don't actually know why they are navigating to different urls if just submitting different numbers. If they are using different urls I have no idea what the appropriate instructions are to go in that section. Your idea is indeed a good one if OP actually wants to bulk submit to same URL. For the top version I am simply making notes on what could be changed in their code and adding the submit line.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for the response. "Bulk check digit calculator" was just an example link that I provided - I do want to pass separate url to edit the content in the website.

Comment: I'll try using the above method and get back to this, thanks!!

Comment: I'm still not able to make it click the submit button - here is the HTML tag associate with the Submit button, please HELP!                                            <span uib-tooltip="An item cannot be submitted until all required attributes are entered for all sections" tooltip-placement="top" tooltip-trigger="mouseenter" tooltip-enable="!createItemsCtrl.isParentFormValid()">Submit</span>

Comment: It sounds like it is saying a field still needs to be completed.

Comment: Have you ensure there is a value in ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value  ? I have tested and it works fine for me.

Comment: Yes, the data that I have in B1 pops up in website but still unable to click on Submit button :(

Comment: Not sure as it works fine for me. Try with .document.getElementById("submit").Click

Comment: I guess you could try adding a wait before the click

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub FillForm()
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Navigate "https://www.morovia.com/bulk-check-digit-calculation/index.php"
IE.Visible = True
While IE.busy
DoEvents
Wend

Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("b1")
IE.Document.getelementbyid("sourceNumbers").Value = Value
IE.Document.getelementbyid("submit").Click
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm still not able to make it click the submit button - here is the HTML tag associate with the Submit button, please HELP! <span uib-tooltip="An item cannot be submitted until all required attributes are entered for all sections" tooltip-placement="top" tooltip-trigger="mouseenter" tooltip-enable="!createItemsCtrl.isParentFormValid()">Submit</span>

Comment: But i was able to click that submit button. and the result was shown in resultbox, If It doesn't work for you then try, IE.document.forms(0).submit

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub FillForm()
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Navigate "https://www.morovia.com/bulk-check-digit-calculation/index.php"
IE.Visible = True
While IE.busy
DoEvents
Wend
For i = 1 to 10 ' Loop according to your Number Of Rows Containing Values
Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value
IE.Document.getelementbyid("sourceNumbers").Value = Value
IE.Document.getelementbyid("submit").Click 'here submit should be in all small letters
Next i
End Sub
```